# Disabling the ClickOnce Trust Prompt

Tags: deployment, clickonce, digital-signature

I'm trying to disable any and all unsigned office ClickOnce Applications from being installed in my organization. By default, ClickOnce displays a trust prompt, asking the user whether they wish to trust the software despite it being unsigned.

[According to the documentation,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-configure-the-clickonce-trust-prompt-behavior?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) the ClickOnce trust prompt can be configured to not be displayed by setting the following registry keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\.NETFramework\Security\TrustManager\PromptingLevel` to "disabled":

- UntrustedSites
- Internet
- MyComputer
- LocalIntranet
- TrustedSites

This way, the users would not be given the option to install software that is not signed.

I tried this, and it has actually worked for a while, but it has recently stopped working for reasons beyond me. It is now displaying the trust prompt again, asking users if they want to install the unsigned software. Researching this topic, the general consensus seems to be that this is the only factor determining whether the trust prompt should be displayed or not.

What am I doing wrong? Why did the trust prompt seemingly randomly start being shown again despite the correct registry keys being set, and how can I stop it from being shown for good?